# ng-show/hide but with Bootstrap's collapse effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

We're using Angular and Bootstrap (note: but not Angular UI Bootstrap). I have a `div` with an `ng-show` on it. What I don't like is that when it shows or hides it doesn't exhibit a collapsing, like you see with Bootstrap's collapse. How can I get this growing/shrinking behavior that collapse uses to work with ng-show? Like, I when ng-show is true, I want to see the element collapse-show. And when ng-show is false, I want the element to collapse-hide.

Comment: got a sample code somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the behaviour of `ngShowDirective` by using a `$decorator` inside of your config.

The same would be possible with a custom directive but then I think it's not possible to use `ng-show`. That was my first approach - creating a new directive in addition to the `ng-show`. But then `ngShow` have always broken the hiding animation.

UI Bootstrap is doing it with a [directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/collapse/collapse.js) that you could call with `collapse="isVisisble"`.

See the demo below and here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/4q7z4oq0/).

It took a while to figure this out but I think that's what you're looking for.

```js
// hide class set in ngShow directive like below (not needed for bootstrap collapse)
//var NG_HIDE_CLASS = 'ng-hide';
//var NG_HIDE_IN_PROGRESS_CLASS = 'ng-hide-animate';

angular.module('myApp', [])
    .config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('ngShowDirective', function ($delegate, $animate) {
        var ngShow = $delegate[0];
        console.log(ngShow);
        ngShow.compile = function (element, attr, transclude) {
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope, element, attr);
                scope.$watch(attr.ngShow, function ngShowWatchAction(value) {
                    console.log('own watch', value, value ? 'show': 'hide');
                    $(element).addClass('collapse');
                    $(element).collapse(value ? 'show': 'hide');
                   
                    /* // org source code below
                    $animate[value ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'](element, NG_HIDE_CLASS, {
                        tempClasses: NG_HIDE_IN_PROGRESS_CLASS
                    });*/
                });
            }
        };
        delete ngShow.link; // delete original link because our compile returns new link method
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-init="visible=false">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="visible = !visible">Toggle info</button>
    <div ng-show="visible">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular Bootstrap uib-collapse

```
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview
```

Comment: Can you give example on how to use that to resolve the question?

Comment: Instead of ng-show use uib-collapse="condition". Before this you have to add angular bootstrap in your bower.json file

Comment: My previous plunkr link is not working. Refer this one http://plnkr.co/edit/lwd2CTzLZLj9ssNuRBGn?p=preview   But this has older version of angular bootstrap